# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden whatever I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to use boto to automate some operations on amazon ec2, but I can't even run the most simple example without getting:

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

My code is:

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
aws_access_key_id='CENSOREDCENSORED',
aws_secret_access_key='CENSOREDCENSOREDCENSOREDCENSORED')

instances = conn.get_all_instances()
```

I'm sure that `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` are correct, because I use them in the CLI Tools and I can succesfully run `ec2-describe-instances`

I'm using boto version: 2.35.1

Comment: is the time accurate on your client machine/server?

Comment: are you credential in  group with require permissions. I had this problem where I was in not group at all so I could not connect using CyberDuck but I could create a client using aws-sdk for ruby.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine for me -- I just tested with boto 2.35.1 and your exact code (with my credentials). Therefore, the problem is either with your credentials or with you network connectivity. Are you behind a firewall, corporate network, proxy or similar?

Comment: @AntarrByrd That! I was not in any group, I've created one now and it worked. If you want to write a small answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by the user @AntarrByrd, the problem was that my user was not in a group with the appropriated permissions (my user wasn't in a group at all).

To fix this using the EC2 Management Console do the following:
If you haven't created any group yet go and create one at `Administration & Security` --> `Identity & Access Management` --> `Groups`.
Then go to `Administration & Security` --> `Identity & Access Management` --> `Users` and add your user to the group.